# I wanted to rename '\' with '\\' in python example:C:\Users\Performance_stats.xlsx with C:\\Users\\Performance_stats.xlsx

Tags: python-3.x

I try to rename '\' with '\\'by using below code but it is showing the error as

```
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

String = "C\users\stat.csv"
String.replace('\','\\')
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Can someone help how to get the output as 
"C\\users\\stat.csv" with rename function.

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of the `pathlib` in python.

```
from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath

# I've explicitly declared my path as being in Windows format, so I can use forward slashes in it.
filename = PureWindowsPath("source_data\\text_files\\raw_data.txt")

# Convert path to the right format for the current operating system
correct_path = Path(filename)

print(correct_path)
# prints "source_data/text_files/raw_data.txt" on Mac and Linux
# prints "source_data\text_files\raw_data.txt" on Windows
```

To read more, you can refer to [this](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f) article.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape each`\`

```
String = "C\\users\\stat.csv"
x=String.replace('\\','\\\\ ')
print (x==String)
print (x)
```

Output as follows:

```
C\\ users\\ stat.csv
```